# SQL Server Deadlocks on cascade deleting

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

The rows are deleted asynchronously with cascade deleting from other tables.
What is the approach to fix the deadlock? Can the related tables rows be locked in transaction?

Here is the xml report:

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process1f5b50928" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process1f5b50928" taskpriority="0" logused="288" waitresource="KEY: 81:72057594039107584 (8194443284a0)" waittime="5575" ownerId="1131789084" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-03-18T10:24:30.773" XDES="0x1b36356a8" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="2" kpid="3604" status="suspended" spid="134" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="3" lastbatchstarted="2019-03-18T10:24:30.790" lastbatchcompleted="2019-03-18T10:24:30.790" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.790" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider"  hostpid="21004"  isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="1131789084" currentdb="81" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0200000064c34002e8fa5b7dac17b29471b98d1653a1e03a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
(@1 int)DELETE [dbo].[Users] WITH(rowlock)   WHERE [Id]=@1    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x020000001485b7340562f882a8e2556c22adf5f74806757d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Users] WITH (ROWLOCK) WHERE Id IN (723540);    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Users] WITH (ROWLOCK) WHERE Id IN (723540);   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process252569c38" taskpriority="0" logused="288" waitresource="PAGE: 81:1:564854 " waittime="4416" ownerId="1131789067" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-03-18T10:24:30.703" XDES="0x1addc76a8" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="5568" status="suspended" spid="76" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="3" lastbatchstarted="2019-03-18T10:24:30.757" lastbatchcompleted="2019-03-18T10:24:30.730" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.730" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostpid="21004"  isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="1131789067" currentdb="81" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0200000064c34002e8fa5b7dac17b29471b98d1653a1e03a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
(@1 int)DELETE [dbo].[Users] WITH(rowlock)   WHERE [Id]=@1    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x020000004cb6d313b5f743b8f2df7ba8dfe667de5ac86d290000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Users] WITH (ROWLOCK) WHERE Id IN (723537);    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Users] WITH (ROWLOCK) WHERE Id IN (723537);   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594039107584" dbid="81" objectname=".dbo.ABSENTSTATUSES" indexname="PK__ABSENTST__3214EC07EB7F77EE" id="lock1df18ec00" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594039107584">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process252569c38" mode="RangeS-U" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process1f5b50928" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="564854" dbid="81" subresource="FULL" objectname=".dbo.Users" id="lock2c6111980" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594039042048">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process1f5b50928" mode="IX" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process252569c38" mode="S" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Here is the deadlock graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Deadlocks is a bit like two hands in a cookie jar.  In this case, you've reduced the scope to a row lock, but there's still two queries that are attempting to delete the same row at the same time.  Can you use a depth column to limit what's deleted to the deepest record first.  Then just work your depth up.  So that you can impact one tier of the tree at a time?